# How can I fix this creation vector in C++

Tags: c++, boost, vector

Im making a program in C++ and i want include `vector` type `Hilo` --> `vector<Hilo>` , (`Hilo` is a class that contains a boost::thread that modify the hilo's attributes itself..) .The bug presents when the vector is created in the file: Operaciones.cpp in `agregarHilo` . What is wrong in the creation of vector ? i have tryed create it with these ways: 
 1.

```
  Hilo * hil = new Hilo(this->contadorHilos,tiempo_vida);
    vecHilos.push_back(hil);
```

or 2. (the vector is created in the method `agregarHilo` from Operaciones.cpp as I said earlier .. here is the complete code ) thanks.

```
//file: Hilo.h    
#ifndef HILO_H   
#define HILO_H1    
#include <boost/thread.hpp>   
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>    
#include <string>    
using namespace std;    
class Hilo{    
private:    
    int id;    
    string mensaje;    
    int tiempo_vida;    
    boost::thread hilo;    
public: void accion();    
        Hilo(int,int);    
        ~Hilo();    
        void setId(int);    
        int getId() const;    
        void setTiempoVida(int);    
        int getTiempoVida() const;    
        string getMensaje() const;    
};//endif    

//file: Hilo.cpp    
#include "Hilo.h"    
#include <iostream>
Hilo::Hilo(int id,int tiempo_vida){    
    this->id=id;    
    this->tiempo_vida=tiempo_vida;    
    this->hilo=boost::thread(&Hilo::accion,this);}    
Hilo::~Hilo(){}    
void Hilo::accion(){    
    unsigned a=1;    
    boost::posix_time::seconds velocidad_(a);    
    while (this->tiempo_vida>=0){    
        stringstream sstm;    
        sstm<<"Hilo numero:"<<this->id <<" tiempo de vida restante:"<<(this->tiempo_vida--);    
        this->mensaje=sstm.str();    
        boost::this_thread::sleep(velocidad_);}    
}    
void Hilo::setId(int id){    
    this->id=id;}    
int Hilo::getId() const{    
    return this->id;}    
void Hilo::setTiempoVida(int tiempo_vida){    
    this->tiempo_vida=tiempo_vida;}    
int Hilo::getTiempoVida() const{   
    return this->tiempo_vida;}    
string Hilo::getMensaje() const{    
    return this->mensaje;}    

//file: Operaciones.h   
#ifndef OPERACIONES_H    
#define OPERACIONES_H1    
#include "Hilo.h"    
#include <vector>
class Operaciones{    
private:    
    int contadorHilos;
    vector<Hilo> vecHilos;    
public:    
    Operaciones();    
    void agregarHilo(int);    
    void verHilo(int);    
};#endif    

    //file: Operaciones.cpp    
    #include "Operaciones.h"    
    Operaciones::Operaciones(){    
        this->contadorHilos=0;}    
void Operaciones::agregarHilo(int tiempo_vida){    
    vecHilos.push_back(Hilo(this->contadorHilos,tiempo_vida); 
    this->contadorHilos++;    
}    
void Operaciones::verHilo(int hilo){} //en construccion    

//file: Principal.cpp    
#include <iostream>    
#include <cstdlib>    
#include "Operaciones.h"    
using namespace std;    

int main(){    
    bool run=true;    
    int opcion;    
    Operaciones oper;    
    system("clear");    
    while(run==true){    
        cout<<"APLICACION MULTI-HILO\nDigite alguna de las opciones\n1. Crear nuevo hilo\n2.Observar hilo\n3. Salir\n";    
        cin>>opcion;    
        switch(opcion){    
        case 1:    
            system("clear");    
            cout<<"Se va a crear un nuevo hilo\n";    
            cout<<"Digite el tiempo de vida del hilo(segundos)";    
            int tiempo;    
            cin>>tiempo;    
            oper.agregarHilo(tiempo);    
            cout<<"Se ha agregado correctamente";    
            break;    
        case 2:    
            system("clear");    
            cout<<"Se va a observar un hilo\n";    
            break;    
        case 3:    
            system("clear");    
            cout<<"Fin del programa, gracias\n";    
            run=false;   
            break;    
        default:    
            system("clear");    
            cout<<"La opcion que ingreso es incorrecta\n";    
            break;    
        }    
        sleep (1.1);    
        system("clear");    
    }    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: You don't need the pointer. http://klmr.me/slides/modern-cpp/#1

Comment: @DiegoParra What error messages do you get?

Comment: 2 is the correct way. What problem do you get when you try this way? Can't really help unless you say what the bug is.

Comment: @quamrana The error message is: initialized.h:256: instantiaded from 'forwardIterator std::__unitialiezed .........and in the final message: not found a matching function for call 'Hilo::Hilo (const Hilo&)' Hilo.h:18: note: candidates are : Hilo::Hilo(int, int) Hilo.h:17: note: Hilo::Hilo() Hilo.h:9: note: Hilo::Hilo(Hilo&)

Comment: Maybe unrelated but I think you are missing a bracket in `vecHilos.push_back(Hilo(this->contadorHilos,tiempo_vida);`.

Comment: Also, avoid unnecessary `this->` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is with the line `vecHilos.push_back(Hilo(this->contadorHilos,tiempo_vida));`.  In this line you are creating a new `const Hilo` object, this is then copied into the back of `vecHilos`.

Most of your class can be copied without hassle, however the `boost::thread` is not copyable:

> The boost::thread class is responsible for launching and managing
>   threads. Each boost::thread object represents a single thread of
>   execution, or Not-a-Thread, and at most one boost::thread object
>   represents a given thread of execution: objects of type boost::thread
>   are not copyable.

You should be able to verify this behaviour by removing all instances of `boost::thread` from your code, it should then compile fine (unless there are other errors).

In this case, you will need to write your own copy (or move) constructor for `Hilo` and handle the copying/moving of the thread.  For example (untested and probably not the best solution):

```
// Move constructor
Hilo::Hilo(Hilo&& old)
  : id(_hilo.id), mensaje(_hilo.mensaje), tiempo_vida(_hilo.tiempo_vida),
    hilo(std::move(_hilo.hilo)) {}
```